# how can i got the recent Saved id of my SQL database in next form

Tags: c#, sql

When i am trying to retrieve the last value from my data base it returns the first one.
By using the following Query.

```
SELECT [Id] from dbo.Tb_Patient;
```

I want to get the last value.
What query i should use?

Comment: Either `SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Tb_Patient] ORDER BY [Id] DESC` or (better) look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert

Comment: ***last value*** ordered by what criteria? A SQL database (whatever product you're using) doesn't have any implicit order - you need to **define** the order you want by issuing `ORDER BY ......` in your query

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Top(1) [Id] from dbo.Tb_Patient order by Id desc;
```

Alternatively if `Id` is Auto Incremented column then you can use `MAX` function as well to find Maximum value.

```
SELECT MAX([Id]) from dbo.Tb_Patient
```

Comment: Assuming `Id` is of a type that orders properly, if it's a GUID etc it won't work.