# How to return the value of Identity element

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in SQL Server with 3 columns `Id` (`int identity`), `email` (`nvarchar(50)`), `password` (`nvarchar(50)`). Now I want to write a query where I can insert `email` and `password` and that time, I want to return the identity element for `id`.

For e.g I insert `abc@dal.ca` and password then the identity element value should be returned.

I wrote it as:

```
@email nvarchar(50), @password nvarchar(50), @id int

insert into addEmail(email, password) 
values(@email,@password)

return @id
```

Is this proper ?? How should I do ? How should I check whether this is working properly or not ? If I select

```
dbo.sp_addEmailReturnId abc@dal.ca, demo
```

and click on execute, it shows

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

I am unable to find the error. I am just trying to insert email id and password so that could be inserted and i would get the identity element which is automatically incremented by 1 with every new row.

In code part for asp.net, how would I retrieve the id. ?

Comment: You can check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)

Comment: you can get auto incremented id by `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. it will give last incremented id. so if there is any trigger called on insert then it may give wrong value..

Comment: I think you should use Damith answer to avoid any misbehaviour of application. As advised by @Sac you might get return wrong value in certain circumstances

Comment: If you're calling a stored procedure to do the INSERT, and if you have the ability to modify that stored procedure, you can add an OUT parameter [see `ParameterDirection`] to your command to hold the autoincremented id; assign SCOPE_IDENTITY() to that parameter's value; back on the client you can get the id value from the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
 private int getEmail(string email, string password) 
 { 
   string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString; 
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs)) 
   {  
     conn.Open(); 
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_addEmailReturnid", conn); 
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email); 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",password); 
     int nUploadId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()); } // Updated Part
```

**NOTE**

At the end of your stored proc i.e after insert statement add

```
Select Scope_Identity()
```

**Edit**

Your proc would be sometihng like this

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_addEmailReturnid]  
    @email                  VARCHAR(500),
    @password       VARCHAR(500)        
AS
BEGIN
 // Your insert statement here

 Select Scope_Identity()

End
```

Comment: If I write query as-----

insert into addEmail(email,password) values(@email,@password)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

would it mean same ??

Comment: The problem I am getting is, when i write the code in asp.net and call the store procedure, it says "procedure has too many arguments specified." I think it returns two things , one is the id number and other is " 1 row affected( as i insert the things also) ". How can i solve this ??

Comment: private int getEmail(string email, string password)



    {


        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))


        {


            conn.Open();


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_addEmailReturnid", conn);



            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",password);


            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



        }

Comment: sorry,, i am unable to edit the code which i just wrote. Sorry for the convinience.

Comment: @user2387900 If you still face any issue. Feel free to ask more

Comment: int nUploadId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            return nUploadId;

I wrote this and still I am getting same error.

IN SP,, I didnt got should I make any change or not.. ?

It is:

insert into addEmail(email,password) values(@email,@password)


 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: @user2387900 you needn't to return anything here. Remove `nUploadId` from code as well as any return statement from stored proc as well

Comment: No I want that identity element, I need to pass that identity element in other function. SO, it is mandatory to return identity element and pass it in other function.

Comment: well that need some sense.. You change it as per your variable name. Also remove any variable you declare in stored proc to return value

Comment: Dear you will get that identity element in this line `int nUploadId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()); `

Comment: yea..i will get that identity element in this line,, so i am just returning nUploadId, as i have made return type int. Bro, i dont know where I am wrong.

Comment: @user2387900 Show me your stored proc or either look at sample stored proc that i have added in my answer

Comment: ok..I got it...thanks alot...help appreciated...
Could u explain me the line: int nUploadId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()); 

So, here it wont take the 1 row affected value ??
what it would do ?

Comment: It will return the value form `Select Scope_Identity()` You can read more about it from google

Answer (score 1):

try

```
insert into addEmail(email,password) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
values(@email,@password)
```

Comment: If I write query as----- insert into addEmail(email,password) values(@email,@password) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() would it mean same ??

Comment: both are same, but you don't need two lines with this way

Answer (score 1):

Try this query; it will fetch you the id

```
insert into addEmail(email, password) values(@email,@password) Select @@IDENTITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Scope_Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

```
insert into addEmail(email,password) values(@email,@password)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: The problem I am getting is, when i write the code in asp.net and call the store procedure, it says 

"procedure  has too many arguments specified." 

I think it returns two things , one is the id number and other is 

" 1 row affected( as i insert the things also) ".

How can i solve this ??