# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error thrown?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in c#. I try to get the last inserted id from an update query. But i get an error
This is my code

```
String Query1 = "insert into test(userid,score) values ('"+userid+"',0);";
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmdDatabase1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, conn1);
SqlDataReader dbreader1;
conn1.Open();
testid = (int)cmdDatabase1.ExecuteScalar();
dbreader1 = cmdDatabase1.ExecuteReader();
while (dbreader1.Read())
{    
}
```

I get this error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   on this line testid = (int)cmdDatabase1.ExecuteScalar();

I have also tried this

```
String Query1 = "insert into test(userid,score) values ('"+userid+"',0);";
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmdDatabase1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, conn1);
SqlDataReader dbreader1;
conn1.Open();
object count = cmdDatabase1.ExecuteScalar();
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(count.GetType());
int testid = (int)count;
dbreader1 = cmdDatabase1.ExecuteReader();
while (dbreader1.Read())
{    
}
```

Same error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`o nthis line System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(count.GetType());

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: String constring = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=geografia;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: try to remove the `Semicolon ;` from the Query1. its useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Return value after INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)

Comment: Try in `debugging mode` and tell which line is actually trowing the `exception`

Comment: if you're trying to get the last inserted ID, use Scope_Identity

Comment: @veer i edited the question, with the lines with the errors. the update is succesful, but I don;t get last insert in a variable.

Comment: I have added a part of the code have a look on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Getting last inserted value from DB, you should write `select` query.

Not a part of this question, but while using `insert` or `select` should make use of `parametrized queries` to avoid `SQLInjections`.

This is a link to learn more bout [SQLInjections](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection&ei=0uCuUffSBcmmrQfB1YDwBw&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&sig2=-OuRqUKg1oVuAo14tAyidA).

your code should be:

```
try
{
  con.open();
  cmd=new SqlCommand("select max(userid) from test",con);
  da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  DataSet ds=new DataSet();
  da.fill(ds);
  int lastInsertedId= int.parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].toString());
  con.close();
}
catch(exception ex)
{
  messagebox.show(ex.Message);
}
```

You can also use different techniques in SQL according to SqlServer you are using such as

`@@identity,rownumber over`. Ofcourse, this can be according to your need and version of SQLServer you are using.

For [RowNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

For [@@identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: not ideal - if somebody adds another record in the meantime, then you're getting the wrong ID.  that's what scope_identity (and to a lesser extent @@identity) are for

Comment: Yup you are right. wait, will Update my answer with this also

Comment: I didn't - in fact I'll +1 for the answer and the mention of sql injection.

Comment: I tried it with update not select, but it can't find table[0]

Comment: You can accept this answer by checking tick after the answer , if its helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to insert as well as select `last inserted id`. Your main problem was 'Object reference not set to an instance of object'. Try the below code.

```
try
{
    String Query1 = "insert into test(userid,score) OUTPUT INSERTED.userid values ('"+userid+"',0);";
    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmdDatabase1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, conn1);
    conn1.open();
    da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmdDatabase1);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    da.fill(ds);
    int Id= int.parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].toString());
    con.close();
}
catch(exception ex)
{
  messagebox.show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Answer edited try it now.Instead of `OUTPUT.ID` write `output.userid`

Answer (score 0):

What line does the error happen on? I'm guessing here:

```
while (dbreader1.Read())
```

why? Because an insert query doesn't result in any rows... but I guess we'd have to check that.

Answer (score 0):

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, try using [ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)