# Using @@identity for consecutive inserts

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have this situation,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1()...
--Get the primary key from the above insert
SELECT @@identidy
INSERT INTO TABLE2()...
```

The auto generated primary key has to be a foreign key in TABLE 2. How can I construct my second INSERT to have the value of @@identity?

This doesn't seem to work,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (user_id, name) (@@identity, 'ABC')
```

I get an error saying `Must declare variable '@@identidy'.`

Cheers!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you spelled `@@identity` wrong (`@@identidy`)

2) You should create a local variable (`@LastIdentity`) to store the last inserted identity immediately after the first insert.  Then use that variable as the input to the second `INSERT`:

```
DECLARE @LastIdentity int

INSERT INTO TABLE1()...
--Get the primary key from the above insert

SELECT @LastIdentity = @@identity

INSERT INTO TABLE2(...) VALUES (@LastIdentity, ...
```

Comment: I just want to take a gun and shoot myself in the face. How did I not see that!! Thanks Stan!!