# SQL Get the row number of the inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the row number of an inserted record so I can use it for a select statement. What I am trying to accomplish is insert a person into one table, get that row number and then select something from another table where the row numbers match. Here is what I got so far:

```
INSERT INTO TableA Values (‘Person’)

Select timeToken
From 
(
    Select 
      Row_Number() Over (Order By tokenOrder) As RowNum
    , *
    From TableB WHERE taken = false
) t2
Where RowNum = (Row Number of Inserted Item)
```

How do I get the row number of the inserted item, I want to compare ids as some records might have been deleted so they would not match.

```
TABLEA Data (primary key is id)

id name
3 John
12 Steve

TABLEB Data (primary key is id)

id timeToken tokenOrder taken
2   1:00am    1          false
3   2:00am    2          false
5   3:00am    3          true
6   4:00am    4          false
```

My expect result when I insert person, the select take would return 4:00am

I am doing this in a stored procedure.

Comment: Do you have `rownum` column in `TableA` ?

Comment: Uh... I think you may be slightly confused about how SQL Server stores data. A row doesn't inherently have a "row number".

Comment: No I do not have a rownum column in TableA

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Comment: I added sample data and expecting reults

Comment: *My expect result when I insert person, the select take would return 4:00am* still not clear add expected result also in table format

Comment: When I insert the value 'Person' to TableA, I am expecting the select to return 4:00am because 'Person' would be the 3rd row and 4:00am would also be the 3rd row as 3:00am taken value is false.

Comment: TableA and TableB do not have any other relations except "row number"? Then, what happens when you delete 1 row in TableA or TableB?

Comment: @TriV thats what I am trying to solve, should I have an relation between TableA and TableB? If so, what would it be??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is an error to think that rows have numbers unless an `ORDER BY` clause is included.
2. The only way to find a row after you have inserted it is to search for it. Presumably your table has a primary key; use that to search for it.

Comment: Yes I primary key like an id, what do I do in the case of deleted records, TableA primary key column could start at 51 or 3 and that would not match the tokenOrder of TableB

Comment: By the sounds of it you are trying to do something like what is listed on thhe following link [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)

Basically : 
'INSERT INTO TableA (Person)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
VALUES('bob');'

Comment: @David I've seen that, but what do I do in the case when a timeToken is false? example 3:00am is taken, so if even I restarted the primary key when finished, the id wont match the tokenOrder I am trying to get

Comment: Oops, Sorry!  I posted multiple times to the question.  I meant to only post the one comment.   I do not immediately have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try This .It may help you out

```
Declare @TableA_PK BIGINT

INSERT INTO TableA Values ('Person')

SET @TableA_PK=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Select timeToken
From 
(
    Select 
      Row_Number() Over (Order By tokenOrder) As RowNum
    , *
    From TableB WHERE taken = false
) t2
Where RowNum =@TableA_PK
```

**SCOPE_IDENTITY():** Scope Identity will captures the last inserted record primary key value and which can be stored in a varaible and
and then it can be for further re-use

Comment: but my ids may not be 1,2,3,4,5,6 it could be something like this 5,6,7,9,11,14,17

Comment: your table coulmn doesn't have the  `IDENTITY` ..??

Comment: timeToken in Table A? No

Comment: I'm asking whether any of the column as Auto Increment (IDENTITY ON) feature on your table..?

Comment: Yes, my id column is auto incremetn primary key, but if I delete testing records, it will start out weird

Comment: if your id column is auto incrementing and you want to display the data related to newly inserted record then the above query will help you.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you are trying to do something like what is listed on thhe following link [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert) - [SQL Server - Return value after INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)

Basically :

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Person)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
VALUES('bob');
```

Comment: I've seen that, but what do I do in the case when a timeToken is false? example 3:00am is taken, so if even I restarted the primary key when finished, the id wont match the tokenOrder I am trying to get

Answer (score 0):

Adding a foreign key constraint(referencing primary key in table A) in table b will be good since you won't be able to delete records from table A without deleting them from table B. It'll be helpful for comparing the records using ID.

Comment: Can I see an example of this @Coder1991

Comment: @user979331 add a column id1 in table b using alter statement as below. alter table table b add id1 int null.                                                           Add foreign key constraint as given below.                                             atler table table b add constraint fk_tbl_b foreign key(id1) references table A(id)

Comment: I could be deleting from either one or in Table B, timeTokens could be marked as taken, which then I would not want to include them.

Comment: @user979331 Are you going to perform delete operations on either of the two tables in Store procedure? If so what is the purpose of the delete operation.

Comment: oh not in the store procedure. I will be deleting test records before hand and some timeTokens will be marked as taken.

Comment: If you delete a record from table B then the same record (record in table A with same id) should get deleted from table A. If you create a foreign key constraint then it is not possible to delete records from table A (Parent table) unless the same records have been deleted from table B (Child table).

Comment: If you have created these two tables (a and b) with parent and child relationships (Primary/Foreign key constraints) then it will be easier for you to delete records from both the tables without breaking the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @rowNum int;

INSERT INTO TableA Values ('Person')

SET @rowNum =SCOPE_IDENTITY()

select * from TableA  where id = @rowNum
```