# How to get data and store it with Boomi?

Tags: sql-server, boomi

I'm using Dell Boomi to send Data from a XML file to a MSSQL Database.
I have a XML file filled with data that needs to go to two different tables in my DB.
The problem is that the second table has a column called containerID, that takes the ID from the first table. But the ID is random generated by the DB.

I tried mapping the xml data to the first table, inserting it to the DB and then started a second process taking the ID of that table, but I don't know how to only store this id information and map it later together with the xml file.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe using two data operations is the simple answer. Your first data operation query should return last inserted id. ref [Return value after INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert#targetText=You%20can%20append%20a%20select,the%20identity%20when%20executed%20scaler.)

Using `Message shape` you can modify the `Current Data` returned from first DB operation
and use that in your second DB operation.

You can get more help from this official [article](https://community.boomi.com/s/article/Database-Integration-Guide-FAQ-2)