# Stored Procedure return default value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

in my database, there is a Stored Procedure with INSERT INTO statement. The problem is I want this stored procedure will return the StudentCode default value, I think it's impossible to use the SELECT TOP 1 statement to get this value because there may be multiple rows inserted at the same time. Any help or suggestions?. Thanks very much

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[AddStudent] 
@StudentName NVARCHAR(255),
@DoB DATETIME,
@Parent NVARCHAR(255),
@ParentContact VARCHAR(16),
@Address NVARCHAR(255),
@Class VARCHAR(6),
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.Student
        ( StudentCode , --I set default this column
          StudentName,
          DateOfBirth
          NameParrent ,
          PhoneContact ,
          AddressParent ,
          Class ,
        )
VALUES  ( DEFAULT , --StudentCode varchar(5)
          @StudentName, --StudentName nvarchar(255)
          @DoB, --DateOfBirth datetime
          @Parent, --NameParrent nvarchar(255)
          @ParentContact, --PhoneContact varchar(16)
          @Address, --AddressParent nvarchar(255)
          @Class --Class varchar(6)
        )
-- How to return StudentCode field
```

Comment: So the same student could register hundreds of times and your code would happily accept that and add hundreds of rows for the same person? And no - date of birth is **DATE** not DATETIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OUTPUT INSERTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause, as explained into official docs:-

> INSERTED
>
> Is a column prefix that specifies the value added by the
> insert or update operation. Columns prefixed with INSERTED reflect the
> value after the UPDATE, INSERT, or MERGE statement is completed but
> before triggers are executed.

so your code is going to be like this:- (is not tested, but it guides you to accurate code)

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[AddStudent] 
@StudentName NVARCHAR(255),
@DoB DATETIME,
@Parent NVARCHAR(255),
@ParentContact VARCHAR(16),
@Address NVARCHAR(255),
@Class VARCHAR(6),

AS

DECLARE @StudentCodeInserted  varchar(5)

INSERT INTO dbo.Student
        ( StudentCode, --I set default this column
          StudentName,
          DateOfBirth
          NameParrent ,
          PhoneContact ,
          AddressParent ,
          Class 
        )

OUTPUT inserted.StudentCode INTO @StudentCodeInserted

VALUES  ( DEFAULT , --StudentCode varchar(5)
          @StudentName, --StudentName nvarchar(255)
          @DoB, --DateOfBirth datetime
          @Parent, --NameParrent nvarchar(255)
          @ParentContact, --PhoneContact varchar(16)
          @Address, --AddressParent nvarchar(255)
          @Class --Class varchar(6)
        )
        
Select @StudentCodeInserted as StudentCodeInserted
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **`Return value after INSERT`**

```
DECLARE @generated_StudentCode  table(StudentCode varchar(5))
INSERT INTO dbo.Student
        ( StudentCode, --I set default this column
          StudentName,
          DateOfBirth
          NameParrent ,
          PhoneContact ,
          AddressParent ,
          Class ,
        )

OUTPUT inserted.StudentCode INTO @generated_keys

VALUES  ( DEFAULT , --StudentCode varchar(5)
          @StudentName, --StudentName nvarchar(255)
          @DoB, --DateOfBirth datetime
          @Parent, --NameParrent nvarchar(255)
          @ParentContact, --PhoneContact varchar(16)
          @Address, --AddressParent nvarchar(255)
          @Class --Class varchar(6)
        )

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @generated_StudentCode
```

Read the following thread to have a better understanding

[SQL Server - Return value after INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert)