# How to get the last inert id from TADOQuery?

Tags: mysql

When using [`mysql.h`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/mysql_8h_source.html), there's a property called `insert_id` on the `MYSQL` connection object. Is there a similar feature when using a `TADOConnection`?

I am well ware of `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`. What I'm asking is: If the C API has that feature, why is that feature missing in the ADO connector, if missing?

And if the only solution is to `INSERT` and `SELECT` the last insert id, are these two queries atomic, can some other `INSERT` queries be executed in-between, from a different connection, and make `LAST_INSERT_ID` return an unexpected value?

Since SQL-Server has [`OUTPUT Inserted.ID`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert) and Postgres has [`RETURNING id`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html), I find MySQL to have made a dumb design choice with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: MySQL is not Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL. If you prefer to use them, go ahead. You already know the answer to your question, there's a complete example in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-faq.html So I don't know why you posted this question except to kvetch about a feature of MySQL that you don't like.

Comment: For the record, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the last inserted value _in the current session_. It doesn't matter if another session inserts another row in the same table, this won't affect the value returned by LAST_INSERT_ID() in your session.