# DbCommand.ExecuteScalar() on multiple queries freezes with Sybase

Tags: sybase, identity-column, dbcommand

I'm working with a legacy Sybase database, on a table that has an `Identity` column. When inserting a value into the table, I need to retrieve the new identity value.

I've been picking up ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/sql-server-best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917695/sql-server-return-value-after-insert). Since the database knows neither `Ident_Current()`, nor `Scope_Identity`, nor that the `Insert` query can have an `Output` clause, I've tried to initialize an `OleDbCommand` with the following:

```
Insert Into DatabaseName..TableName 
(Tbl_ColumnA, Tbl_ColumnB, Tbl_ColumnC, Tbl_ColumnD, Tbl_ColumnE, 
Tbl_ColumnF, Tbl_ColumnG) 
Values (
'Valid string for column A', 'Valid string for column B', 'Same for column C', 'And for D', 
'And E', 'And F too', Null
) ; Select Max(Tbl_Id) From DatabaseName..TableName;
```

When the execution reaches `OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar()`, it seems to freeze. (Pausing the debug shows that it's still on that instruction, but it doesn't appear to do anything.)

Checking the contents of `TableName` shows that the new row has duly been inserted in `TableName`.

But I don't get any results.

I've also tried replacing `Select Max(Tbl_Id) From DatabaseName..TableName;` with `Select @@Identity;`, but that doesn't appear to improve the situation.

What am I doing wrong?

(Alternately, I could run the two queries separately in a single transaction, but I'd also like to know why my solution isn't working.)

Comment: sorry, can't speak to the freeze/hang issue; in the meantime ...  please update the question (and tag?) to state which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version; `select max()` is never a good idea as you could pick up the value from someone else's `insert` that was executed between your `insert` and `select max()`; for Sybase ASE the `select @@identity` should suffice ... assuming  you're not firigng a trigger that is running additional inserts of rows with an identity column => then `@@identity` is going to be overwritten based on the trigger's `insert`)

Comment: @markp-fuso: quite right about `@@Identity`, somehow I thought it returned the last identity value generated, period (which would make it even worse than `Select Max()` because someone else could `Insert` in another table). Thanks!

Comment: @markp-fuso: I'm trying to find the info you're asking for about the database, but I'm not sure where to look. (I only have access to the database through a VS connection string, or SQL developer, or Sybase Central, whose Help or Properties don't give me enough clues to work with.)